# About finite decimal

Tags: proof-explanation

It is well known that $0.0\dot9=0.1$ and we say $0.1$ is finite decimal. And $0.0\dot9$ is a repeating decimal.

This is concluded that $\text{finite decimal } = \text{ infinite decimal}$ which is a contradiction.

How is this possible?

Comment: It is only a statement about the notation of the numbers. Not about the number(s) itself. It is legal to have different notations of the same thing. Your equality sign is misplaced here.

Comment: $0.1 = 0.1 \dot0$

Comment: The "Morning star" is the planet Venus. The "Evening star" is planet venus. Therfore, morning = evening, contradiction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$0.09999999999\cdots=0.10000000000\cdots$$

Contradiction ?

Comment: No that's not a contradiction but 'finite decimal = infinite decimal' this was a contradiction.   equality sign was misplaced..